# About Session in J2EE to add to cart(Array list)

Tags: java, session

```
List cart = null;
if(null==session.getAttribute("cart"))
    cart = new ArrayList();
else
    cart = (List)session.getAttribute("cart");
cart.add(item);
session.setAttribute("cart",cart);
response.sendRedirect("ProductDetail?code=" + id);
```

I'm trying to understand the code, but I still don't not quite understand everything. Can anyone please explain it to me?

The code is part of my online store website which is the part where we store the product in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

PLease point what part of code is not clear?
Actually it is standard way...

1. request comes with item to put into cart
2. Cart is an ArrayList stored as **session** attribute
3. If there is no cart in **session** yet (i.e. first request) then new ArrayList creates
4. an item goes into list as next element and cart stores into session

that's it.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer i got it now